# How to add "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" via csv import

Tags: product, import

I want to set Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart to specific value depend on product. Is there any way to add via csv import? I try with max_sale_qty keyword. But it doesn't work.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: can you describe what happens when you use `max_sale_qty`? It seams to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug regarding this in Magento:

https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/3
https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/issues/4

We've been using AvS_FastSimpleImport to import products. This module aims to give a simple interface (regular PHP array) to import your products and fixes bugs in the importer. You might note that there still is some discussion going on if it indeed has been fixed, so your results may vary.

Magento 1.9:
https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L1860-L1865

AvS_FastSimpleImport:
https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/blob/master/src/app/code/community/AvS/FastSimpleImport/Model/Import/Entity/Product.php#L1168-L1173